# Functional Dependency Term

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I'm trying to figure out some issues about functional dependencies (databases). Is this implication true or false and why?

if A->B then AC->B

Thank you so much!

My solution:

Assume that A is a subset of B then B->A (Armstrong rule). Therefore AC->B because A is a subset of AC. If AC->A and A->B then AC-> B, according to transitivity rule.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A alone functionally determines B then adding redundant attributes to the left hand side of the relationship will not alter the truth of the original dependency.

Basically this is the Augmentation rule form [Armstrons Axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) which states that if A -> B then A,C -> B,C. Then by decomposition A,C -> B

Comment: Thank for you response, now it is clear for me.